# Android resource compilation failed (values.xml:200: error: invalid color)

Tags: android, kotlin

I just begin learning Android with Kotlin, and I'm learning to build sliding intro. During build of my android application, I'm getting following error:

[image]

things in my `color.xml`:

[image]

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:D:\HCI_Retry\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:200: error: invalid color.

Command: C:\Users\Nasri\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\bdf42a08a9c0a8f46dee8cc9eb34b57b\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\HCI_Retry\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
D:\HCI_Retry\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #7
```

I have tried to find solution toward my problem, but non of the solution actually helped with my problem. I had tried to open the values.xml file in hope to find the problem, but still got no clue.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's in your colors.xml?

Comment: Could you paste the error message in the question directly instead of using an image? Referencing will work better if the algorithm is able to read the error (does not work on images ;)). There is a nice formatting tool for pasting source code/logs. :)

Comment: @TheWanderer I have added the content of colors.xml

Comment: @DavidGuyon I have added the error message, but I'm not sure if that's the correct thing to do :'(

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please paste the whole `colors.xml` file content by editing your question.

Comment: @Mohsen Thank you, the code above is the whole file, except the </resource>.

Comment: What exactly is in the line 200 of D:\HCI_Retry\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml?

Answer (score 7):

From the `colors.xml` image, it looks like the issue is the missing `#` in `colorHighlight`. Should be `#B6B6B6` instead of just `B6B6B6`.

Answer (score 3):

KaiRuCheng disappeared and did not post line 200 of colors.xml as was asked in comments, but for all who is looking for solution for similiar problem:
I was encountered the same and found that it was just quotes around color code. I had this:

```
<color name="paragraph">"#FF0074E1"</color>
```

But should have to have this:

```
<color name="paragraph">#FF0074E1</color>
```

Note quotes around color code. It seems to be obvious error but despite of it Android Studio rendered correctly all elements which are using that color, and this error appears during building only.

I am not sure if this was the reason for KaiRuCheng's problem, as we can't see line 200 of his/her colors.xml, but this definetly was a reason for my problem which looked exactly same.

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer: for me, I had typed `#color/something` instead of `@color/something ...` Android Studio would not underline it and the difference was so small, it took me 15 minutes to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered with such problem when upgrading to Gradle 3.3.2. In my case, it was using Cyrillic instead Latin

```html
<color name="default_button_press">#cc3b3b3b</color>
```

cc was Cyrillic and Android Studio didn't underline on old Gradle version.